# Draw line above Mapkit: Invalid Region error

Tags: iphone, mapkit, region

I'am trying to draw a line above mapkit.
If I try to set the region my app crashes:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region <center:-106.01842850, +37.33390400 span:+0.01000000, +0.01000000>'
```

span waas set manually.

Why does mapkit says that this is an invalid region?

thanks!

If you need more code just let me know...

Already solved: the routing source changed lat and long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the same problem.

what do you mean by "the routing source changed lat and long" ?

EDITED AND SOLVED : under sdk 3.1, latitudeDelta can't be left to 0 like on 3.0, so that's the reason the app is crashing.

Comment: ok : I found out. I am working on a project that complies on 3.0 sdk, but if you change your emulator to 3.1.3 (didn't test for others sdk), you get the error.
So back to apple white sheets to understand that.